# React Private Route redirects before firebase user is loaded

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to create a private route for 2 pages. However, my private route does the checking of if a user is logged in or not before firebase can update it.

So the moment the private route is called, the user will return null. And this means it will immediately redirect me to the login page even though I am logged in as a user.

How can I make the user be ready for the private route to detect it?

```
function App() {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const user = useSelector(selectUser);

 useEffect(() => {
   auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
     if (authUser) {
       // the user is logged in
       console.log('user is ', authUser);
       dispatch(
         login({
           uid: authUser.uid,
           email: authUser.email,
         })
       );
     } else {
       //the user is logged out
       dispatch(logout());
     }
   });
 }, [dispatch]);
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <Switch>
       <PrivateRoute exact path="/" user={user} component={Home} />
       <PrivateRoute
         exact
         path="/workout"
         user={user}
         component={WorkoutCreator}
       />
       <Route eact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
       <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
     </Switch>
   </div>
 );
}
```

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, user, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return user ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }}
    ></Route>
  );
}
```

```
function Login() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) history.push('/');
  }, [user, history]);

  function onSubmit(data) {
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    console.log(user);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize a boolean variable called "authenticating" to true and when you are done detecting if the user is logged in or logged out, then set variable "authenticating" to false.
Only after that check if the user is null or not.

Comment: I believe we answered on the same time :). Thank you, that is what I did to solve my problem. I hope it was implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I used a loader to wait till the components were loaded.

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        // the user is logged in
        console.log('user is ', authUser);
        dispatch(
          login({
            uid: authUser.uid,
            email: authUser.email,
          })
        );
      } else {
        //the user is logged out
        dispatch(logout());
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!loading && (
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" user={user} component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute
```